# How to replace 1i and make 2i, 3i, 4i possible?

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers

In matlab, `1i` represents an imaginary unit.

1. Is it possible to modify `1i`?
2. Is it possible to assign my own definition for `2i`, `3i` and etc?

Thanks!

Edit: Since I am a bit uncomfortable with the down vote, I should clarify my application here:

My goal is to extend the complex number class in Matlab. Why? Because the built-in complex number in Matlab is only for simple complex number. That is, if you have multi-complex number such as bi-complex number in the form of:

> z = a + b*(1i) + c*(2i) + d*(1i)*(2i)

Where `1i` and `2i` are the bi-complex numbers, the capability of modifying the built-in definition of `1i` and `2i` in Matlab would make multi-complex number operation more convenient.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What do you mean by "modify `1i`"?

Comment: No, it's not possible! The syntax `1i`, `2i`... is reserved for imaginary units.

Comment: @ rayryeng: modify as in redefine it. please see my edit for more clarification. Thanks!

Comment: @ Rotem: regrettably, 1i, 2i, 3i,... are in the same complex number plane. My intention is to redefine 1i, 2i, 3i each corresponding to different complex number plane. Please see my edit for more clarification. Thanks!

Comment: If you tell what input/s do you  have and what will be the output , your questions may be understood. As of now, I don't understand what you're asking!

Comment: In this case, sure.  Make a new MATLAB class.

Answer (score 0):

No. `i` is a function in matlab, and it can be overwritten by your own function or variable. However, matlab ignores your other definitions when `i` is immediately preceded by a number with no separating whitespace, like `1 + 2i`.

Suppose I created a file `i.m` containing that had a function `i` which takes no arguments and returns 321. Then I run the following script:

```
i = 123;
disp(i); % my variable
disp(i()); % my function
disp(1i); % builtin i
```

The code produces the following output.

```
123
321
0.0000 + 1.0000i
```

There's nothing you can do about `1i`. However, if you're okay with writing `1*i`, then you can do pretty much whatever you want.

See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am looking for more than that. Please see my edit for further clarification.